# How can I get drone.io running at a certain path?

Tags: nginx, continuous-integration

I would like to have my drone installation running behind my nginx server. I want to access it under `http://host/drone`, but it doesn't seem to get the path option.

My nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myhost.io;

  location ~ ^/drone/(.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8042/$1;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

And my configuration file like this:

```
DRONED_OPTS="--port=:8042 --path='/drone'"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the `--path` option is the path to the sqlite database. While you can run Drone behind a proxy, you might get strange behavior (bugs) if you try to use a path prefix.

Comment: So what do you recommend? Should I run drone in a subdomain?

Comment: yes, a subdomain should work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Brad Rydzewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160454/brad-rydzewski) figured out, the --path option is only for the path to the sqlite database and drone can't be run in a subtree.